# What is the meaning of "All i need" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

I am reading the book, Diary of a Wimpy kid.

What is the meaning of "All i need" in the sentence, "All I need is for some jerk to catch me carrying this book around and get the wrong idea." ?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually

> all I need

means there is only one thing which is necessary

> All I need is a glass of water.

However, in your example

> all I need

is a sarcastic remark which actually means the opposite

> what I really don't need is for some jerk...

Context is very important to discern the meaning.

Answer (score 0):

It means "The last thing I need...".

Something you don't need and maybe fear.